# How to get user role from db in variable in C# and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, authentication

I am working on the C# project and database in MySQL. Everything is working fine, but I just want to get user role with email and password. I am getting user email and password, but I don't know how I get user roles during login of the user in a global variable. Please see my code and help me that how can it be done.

Here is the image of my database
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3sO7.png

Here is my code

```
if (!Helper.CustomTextbox.ValidateContainer(this))
{
    Bunifu.Snackbar.Show(this, "Validation error.", 3000, Snackbar.Views.SnackbarDesigner.MessageTypes.Error);
    return;
}
var user = Program.db.GetRecord<User>($"email LIKE '{txtEmail.Text}' AND password like '{txtPassw.Text}'");
if(user==null)
{
    Bunifu.Snackbar.Show(this, "Invalid credentials, Contact Admin.", 3000, Snackbar.Views.SnackbarDesigner.MessageTypes.Error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the various other significant issues with your example code... please show the body of `Program.db.GetRecord<User>()`. If `Role` is a field belonging to the `User` table, then you need to configure the mapping to a property of your `User` object in your ORM.

Comment: can you clarify it is it not possible to do this with my code or its necessary to work on class also

Comment: That's impossible to answer given the code you have presented in the question.

Comment: so which type of code you want for answer

Comment: Please show your `User` class. Does it have a `Role` field? Is this correctly mapped to your table?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/67zHdiU.png
brother check my user class